# Update specific model attributes from a request

Tags: php, laravel

## Background

This is for an API and I'd like to use this Upsert action to take data from a request and only update the requested fields. I.e. These are partial updates and I will not update every field from a model in every request. A previous version from examples I was working through took the incoming data and updated all fields which resulted in a lot of nulls which overwrote the original models.

A rough old example was along the lines of:

```
$model->attribute1 = $modelData->attribute1;
$model->attribute2 = $modelData->attribute2;
$model->save();
```

Please don't review that code, I know it's garbage.

I was thinking about doing something hideous and long-winded like checking for the presence of each one like this:

```
if ($modelData->attribtue1 !== null) {
    $model->attribute1 = $modelData->attribute1;
}
```

I was also thinking perhaps I could iterate over the keys of the incoming model data and only update those but that feels like it could be exploited.

## My solution

My solution was to pull in the fillable attributes from the model and iterate over those instead. My current solution is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Actions;

use App\DataTransferObjects\MyModelData;
use App\Models\MyModel;

class UpsertMyModelAction
{
    public function execute(MyModel $myModel, MyModelData $myModelData): MyModel
    {
        $attributes = app(MyModel::class)->getFillable();
        
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            /* if ($myModelData->{$attribute} !== null) { */
            /* 
             * Edit - this won't let me set a value to null 
             * if I want to. Altered to check specifically
             * for the property instead.
             */
            if (property_exists($myModelData, $attribute)) {
                $myModel->{$attribute} = $myModelData->{$attribute};
            }
        }
        
        $myModel->save();

        return $myModel;
    }
}
```

My thinking being that the fillable attributes are defined and controlled by me, this looks a lot cleaner than writing an if statement per attribute and it should be re-usable for different requests.

This MUST come up all the time, I just haven't found any good examples online. How does this look? Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ## How does this look?

It looks okay. It appears to mostly adhere to [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) and is easy to read. While there is only one method with a single loop it isn't very complicated. The variable names are appropriate.

> ## Is there a cleaner way?

I’ve used Laravel for more than 8 years and grown to primarily use controller methods to update models. I've read about using the repository pattern to have thin controllers methods. I haven't seen the manual mention actions though I do see the [laravel-actions package](https://github.com/lorisleiva/laravel-actions) - is that what is being utilized here?

If you look at the source of the [`update()` method within src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent
/Model.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L984) notice that the last line of the method calls the `fill()` method before calling the `save()` method.

> ```
> /**
>  * Update the model in the database.
>  *
>  * @param  array  $attributes
>  * @param  array  $options
>  * @return bool
>  */
> public function update(array $attributes = [], array $options = [])
> {
>     if (! $this->exists) {
>         return false;
>     }
>
>     return $this->fill($attributes)->save($options);
> }
> ```

The [`fill()` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L508) calls `$this->fillableFromArray()` passing along the `$attributes` parameter.

> ```
> /**
>  * Fill the model with an array of attributes.
>  *
>  * @param  array  $attributes
>  * @return $this
>  *
>  * @throws \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException
>  */
> public function fill(array $attributes)
> {
>     $totallyGuarded = $this->totallyGuarded();
>
>     $fillable = $this->fillableFromArray($attributes);
> ```

And [that method calls `getFillable()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php#L247) to determine which attributes can be filled based on the `$attributes` parameter.

> ```
> /**
>  * Get the fillable attributes of a given array.
>  *
>  * @param  array  $attributes
>  * @return array
>  */
> protected function fillableFromArray(array $attributes)
> {
>     if (count($this->getFillable()) > 0 && ! static::$unguarded) {
>         return array_intersect_key($attributes, array_flip($this->getFillable()));
>     }
>
>     return $attributes;
> }
> ```

Consequently one can simply call the `update()` method passing in the attributes to be set on the model. The `foreach` loop can be removed and the `save()` call replaced with a call to `update()` - using a method to get the attributes from `MyModelData` or with a reflection class and its [`getProperties()` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm not using laravel-actions. I've been trying to follow SOLID principles and pulled the Create and Update methods in to this single Upsert action.